# External Keyboard 'd' key causes any window to go out of control and OS to freeze

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a [Jellycomb](https://www.jellycomb.com/) external keyboard which I'm trying to use on my MSI GS65 running Ubuntu. It was working fine with my old laptop also running Ubuntu (Razer Blade), but for some reason it acts weird now. In particular, the 'd' causes any active window (like the browser window or a terminal) to start resizing uncontrollably, and then my OS will just freeze and I'll have to restart my laptop. This doesn't always happen, but it happens quite often. For example, I'm typing this using my external keyboard, and I've typed 'd' a couple of times, and nothing happened. I'm presuming this is because I'm in a "text typing" area so the window that's currently active, my browser, isn't interpreting the 'd' as a signal to it). However, another key acts weird here, the space bar, but not always. It sometimes resizes my window, but not uncontrollably like the 'd' key. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try a different keyboard.

Comment: @heynnema That's what I'll do next but I wanted to see if there is anything I could try and configure before having to buy a new one

Comment: Try a different USB port.

Comment: @heynnema I did, had the same issue

Comment: Check your BIOS with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for a newer BIOS.